# How to use Go package that is in another module

Tags: go, github, import, go-modules

I have two repos github.com/x/a and github.com/x/b and they both have Go modules at the root of each. How can i access a package that that is in the other repo? Normally I would be able to access it by doing a `go get github.com/x/b` if I want to use b in a. But neither are in production and we are still working in a development branch so I need to find a way to do this locally. Any ideas?

Comment: [Can I work entirely outside of VCS on my local filesystem?](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way is to clone the repository into GOPATH/src. Then you can import the packages simply with

`import "a"` or `import "b"`